# Как пропорционально уменьшить фон при изменении размера экрана?

Tags: html, jquery, css, css3

Мне нужно, чтобы фон не обрезался, а пропорционально уменьшался при меньших разрешениях экрана.

Естественно, хочу добиться этого стилями, но `background-size: cover;` не выручает..

[пример тут](http://jsfiddle.net/mwbaqusx/)

```css
.cover {
  background: url(http://placehold.it/1920x1080) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1080px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cover"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Может так?

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.cover {
    background: url(http://placehold.it/1920x1080) no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    padding-top: 56.25%; /* 1080px/1920px = 0.5625 */
}
```

```html
<div class="cover"></div>
```

Comment: да, спасибо помогло! Хотя, почему так казалось бы неочевидная замена `height` на `padding` &